# NullPointerException in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner Selenium practitioner. I have 2 classes, one for the WebDriver another is for Log In. I followed some youtube tutorials but can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong. I tried the concept of 'Baseclass' where I extend the other class.

[LogIn Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnRLS.png)

[WebDriver Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDEXr.png)

If I add the WebDriver in the other class, it will run successfully. But I want to make it more 'organized'

this is the error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHYxQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

public Webdriver driver;

Please add static in this line

**public static Webdriver driver;**

because you need use same driver instance for all classes

create above line in top of both classes

Comment: I actually tried that but still got the same problem.

Comment: Can you use utils class which i wrote and use for chrome function by singleton you can ignore nullpoint exception 

if you are ok I can provide that utils class to use

Comment: that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestApp {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static TestApp myObj;
    // public static WebDriver driver;
    utils.PropertyFileReader property = new PropertyFileReader();

    public static TestApp getInstance() {
        if (myObj == null) {
            myObj = new TestApp();
            return myObj;
        } else {
            return myObj;
        }
    }

    //get the selenium driver
    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    //when selenium opens the browsers it will automatically set the web driver
    private void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static void setMyObj(TestApp myObj) {
        TestApp.myObj = myObj;
    }

    public void openBrowser() {


        //String chromeDriverPath = property.getProperty("config", "chrome.driver.path");
        //String chromeDriverPath = property.getProperty("config", getChromeDriverFilePath());
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getChromeDriverFilePath());
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void navigateToURL() {

        String url =property.getProperty("config","url");
     ;
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(TestApp.getInstance().getDriver(), timeout).until
                (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }

    private String getChromeDriverFilePath()
    {
        // checking resources file for chrome driver in side main resources
        URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver.exe");
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}





//create package name called utils and under that package create class name with TestApp and paste above code 



if you want use driver anywhere in your project 

        TestApp.getInstance().getdriver();
```

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - utils.PropertyFileReader cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Error in line 18:  utils.PropertyFileReader property = new PropertyFileReader();

Sorry im noob

Comment: are you using page object model in selnium ?
using maven ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize your driver anywhere.

You need to use a before

```
@BeforeClass
    public void setupClass(){
        driver = new Chromedriver();
    }
```

and in opensite

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

Answer (score 0):

You want your OpenSite class to act as the base class which you can extend it to your test class to intialize your driver. Remove your "@test" annotaion from the OpenSite class.

1. Add static with "public WebDriver driver";
2. Create a method openBrowser(already there) or driverInitialization in this class.
3. Return the driver instance.

Updated code will look like

```
public class OpenSite{
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void openBrowser(){
System.setProperty("webdriver","path");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("your URL");
return driver;
}
}  
And in test class LogIn extend this class and call this method:
public class LogIn extends OpenSite{
@BeforeTest
public void driver initialization(){
openBrowser();
}
@Test
public void logInVendor(){
//Write your code here 
}
}
```